# Disable file sharing in Skype

Tags: macos, ubuntu, skype

I am unable to find a way to disable file sharing option for Skype in Ubuntu, I did do it for windows by using registry editor.

I would like to know if there is a way to do this in Ubuntu and Mac OS X as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976881/ubuntu-skype-disable-sharing-files) on Stack Overflow. The OP gives a few possibilities:

> By editing /etc/dbus-1/system.d/skype.conf or /etc/dbus-1/system.conf
>
> By adding new entry in the gconf (but skype isn't listed there)
>
> By adding a Skype public api (but then users should not be able to remove it)

Unfortunately the possibility of using an alternative client for Skype supporting this feature is not available anymore, since Microsoft canned SkypeKit.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible currently. Right now, it is possible to disable the file transfer *notifications* in Skype options, but not to disable file transfers.

Ubuntu: v4.x.x `Skype > Options > Notifications`

Mac: v4.x.x or 5 `Skype > Preferences > Notifications > Details`

Comment: What version of Skype for the platforms in the questions had this option?

Comment: 4.3 Ubuntu Do not know about Mac. It is in Options, look around.

Comment: @ChrisBurgess I called Skype and they said that there is no way. If the notifications are bothering you, turn them off.

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer. Have edited answer slightly to clarify - hoping edit can be reviewed/accepted after bounty awarded :D